# fetchAll causes "Cannot read property" error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

I have a database with "firstname" and "lastname" columns in my Users table. Using Ajax, I want to fetch all the users whose names start with, let's say S and then display both their first and last names in a list. So it should show me something like:

- Sara Anderson
- Shaun West

This is what I use to fetch the list of users:

```
public function searchName($searchName)
{
    $pdo = Db::connect();
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE :searchName OR lastname LIKE :searchName");
    $stmt->execute(['searchName' => '%' . $searchName . '%']);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;
}
```

And this is my JS function to loop the results

```
function viewResults(result) {
   const results = document.getElementById("results");
   results.innerHTML = "";

   for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          const li = document.createElement("li");
          li.innerHTML = result['i'];
          results.appendChild(li);
   }
}
```

When I run this, it displays the correct amount of list items, however all the list items are **"undefined"**. I cannot use:

```
li.innerHTML = result['i']['firstname']['lastname'];
```

The above does work just fine when I use fetch() instead of fetchAll(), the only problem is that fetch() only returns one user. I'm guessing the problem is that fetchAll() returns an array inside an array? I've tried using both foreach and while in my SQL query, but none of which helped.

Comment: Have you tried `li.innerHTML = result['i']['firstname'] +'  ' + result[i]['lastname'];`? I think each result[i] would have two properties namely, `firstname` and `latname` and each should be accessed individually.

Comment: @DhruvShah Thank you for your suggestion! I've tried with just ['i']['firstname'] (omitting the last name) but that just gave me the following error in the console: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined**

Comment: In that case, you might need to check the content inside `result`. You can try adding a `console.log(result)` inside the `viewResult` method and check what are the contents inside `result`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the following line:

```
li.innerHTML = result['i'];
```

And also in the alternative you tried:

```
li.innerHTML = result['i']['firstname']['lastname'];
```

The `result` object is an array, so it has no property called "i". You need to use the variable `i`, not the string literal "i". So access `result[i]`.

Secondly, when you retrieve the `firstname` property, you will get a string. But then you try to find a property `lastname` *of that string*. That will not work. Instead you should retrieve `lastname` separately, again on `result[i]`.

Finally, it is better practice to not use `innerHTML` when you assign plain text. `innerHTML` is intended for assigning HTML encoded data. Use `textContent` for plain text data.

So, that line should read:

```
li.textContent = result[i].firstname + " " + result[i].lastname;
```

The code can look a bit nicer (I think) when using a `for...of` loop with destructuring:

```
function viewResults(result) {
   const results = document.getElementById("results");
   results.innerHTML = "";

   for (const { firstname, lastname } of result) {
       const li = document.createElement("li");
       li.textContent = firstname + " " + lastname;
       results.appendChild(li);
   }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm now, thank you so much! And thank you for taking the time to explain what I did wrong, it makes sense now :)